# Как убрать required у Form field

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony, symfony3

Есть `FormType1` создаю `FormType2`

Пишу метод

```
public function getParent()
    {
        return FormType1::class;
    }
```

Достаю в *buildForm*

```
$builder->remove('myfield');
```

Далее есть поле  name c атрибутом `required`

```
$builder->get('name');
```

**Вопрос как убрать `required` у этого поля?**

Answer (score 0):

Кажется вам нужно переопределить данное поле, примерно так:

```
$builder->set('name', null, [
    'required' => false,
]);
```